# Drupal6 how to hide primary navigation

Tags: theming

Is there any function like is_page(like in word press) in Drupal 6

so that I can hide primary navigation menu which is (printed using echo statement) in `page.tpl.php`.

My requirement is to hide navigation menu in certain pages (custom theme).

Answer (score 0):

There is [drupal_is_front_page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_is_front_page/6)

`Check if the current page is the front page`.

**Return value**

Boolean value: TRUE if the current page is the front page; FALSE if otherwise.

Comment: i am new to drupal can u please explain me what it does is_front_page

Comment: Check the manual, it explains all including the return value and what does it do etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to decide to show or not to show your menu on a theme level you can use

- `$is_front` in your `page.tpl.php` to decide whether it's your front page or not

  ```
  <?php if ($is_front && isset($primary_links)): ?>
    <?php print theme('links', $primary_links, array('class' =>'links', 'id' => 'navlist')) ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
  ```
- `$node` if your page is build by rendering a node (Simple page for instance)

  ```
  <?php if (($node && !in_array($node->nid, array(1,2,3))) && isset($primary_links)): ?>
    <?php print theme('links', $primary_links, array('class' =>'links', 'id' => 'navlist')) ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
  ```

  In the above example the primary links are not rendered if you're viewing a node page where the node id is one of 1, 2 or 3. Comapare your path (`node/2`) or the path to edit the page/node if you are using the *path* module to get the *id*
- If that didn't do the trick for you you should dig deeper into some preprocess possibilities using [hook_preprocess](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_preprocess/6) but for that you need to provide further information.